# Minecraft: How to give an effect to a certain player standing on a block on multiplayer?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Hey I am making a multiplayer map and it includes magical blocks that will give you certain effects for example:

```
/execute @p[r=10000] ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ wool 15 /effect @p invisibility 12 3 true
```

which gives invisibility when the "nearest" player stands on it. How can I give the effect to the player who stands on it, not just the nearest player to the commandblock giving the command?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason it is selecting the closest player to the command block is because you have set the selector to `@p`, which selects the closest player to the command block to fit the rule...

You're better off selecting everybody who the rule fits to run the command on.

```
/execute @a[r=10000] ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ wool 15 effect @p invisibility 12 3 true
```

This command executes the `/effect` command on everybody who is within 10,000 blocks of your command block **and** has a Black Wool block under their feet.

Also, when specifying the command to run, you do not need a second slash.
Secondly, **don't forget to run this command in a redstone clock!**

Comment: Question: Would this be able to work with multiple people standing on that                                     block. And when I tested this command with multiple villagers (Since I got no one to test it with) they all became invisible.

Comment: @Phoenix81167 There's a difference between `@a` and `@e`. If you want only *all* players, then use `@a`. If you want *all* entities (including Ender Dragons and dropped items), use `@e`. | btw, Villagers **are not** players. They have to be selected with `@e[type=Villager]`

Comment: Oh ok. Thank you for the information and I hope I can do the rest of the commands on my own. ;)

Answer (score 0):

VERSION 1.16+

```
execute at @a[distance=10000] if block ~ ~-1 ~ [block] run effect give @p [effect] [seconds] [amplifier] true
```